# How to Load list of items on scroll but not all items at the same time to improve performance

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having more than 700+ records and they are loading at the same time, this is effecting performance which takes around 7 seconds .

I am looking for something where only first 20 records display and on scroll down second 20 and so on . I am looking for this type of functionality in redux with react.

Comment: You should look into this wonderful library https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Since the term you are referring to is "Lazy Loading", you may also want to checkout https://github.com/jasonslyvia/react-lazyload

Comment: @shubham i am looking without any library

Comment: For this scenario, you have to add pagination in your code.

Comment: Like @PulkitAggarwal said. Pagination. You’ll have to send only the specific amount of records you want from the backend at start, and then keep sending more when the user has scrolled to a certain point on your page with a listener that can fire off your redux action to fetch more records.